# Creating a small python program with cx_Freeze and pyGTK

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, pygtk, cx-freeze, glade

I'm writing a small test-program that using python 2.7 and pygtk. 
I will use Glade too

I need freeze this with cx_freeze.

**This is my little program:**

```
import gtk

win = gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

**And this is my setup:**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os, site, sys

## Get the site-package folder, not everybody will install
## Python into C:\PythonXX
site_dir = site.getsitepackages()[1]
include_dll_path = os.path.join(site_dir, "gnome")



## Collect the list of missing dll when cx_freeze builds the app
missing_dll = ['libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
               'libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
               'libatk-1.0-0.dll',
               'libcairo-gobject-2.dll',
               'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll',
               'libjpeg-8.dll',
               'libpango-1.0-0.dll',
               'libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll',
               'libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll',
               'libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll'
               # 'libgnutls-26.dll',
               # 'libgcrypt-11.dll',
               # 'libp11-kit-0.dll'
]

## We also need to add the glade folder, cx_freeze will walk
## into it and copy all the necessary files
glade_path = os.path.join(site_dir, "gtk-2.0\\runtime\include\libglade-2.0\\")
glade_folder = 'glade'
# glade_folder = os.path.join(site_dir, "gtk-2.0\\")
# glade_folder += "runtime\include\libglade-2.0\glade"



## We need to add all the libraries too (for themes, etc..)
gtk_libs = ['etc', 'lib', 'share']

## Create the list of includes as cx_freeze likes
include_files = []
for dll in missing_dll:
    include_files.append((os.path.join(include_dll_path, dll), dll))

## Let's add glade folder and files
include_files.append((glade_path, glade_folder))

## Let's add gtk libraries folders and files
for lib in gtk_libs:
    include_files.append((os.path.join(include_dll_path, lib), lib))

base = None

## Lets not open the console while running the app
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [
    Executable("hello.py",
               base=base
    )
]

buildOptions = dict(
    compressed=False,
    includes=["gi"],
    packages=["gi"],
    include_files=include_files
    )

setup(
    name="test_gtk3_app",
    author="my name",
    version="1.0",
    description="GTK 3 test",
    options=dict(build_exe=buildOptions),
    executables=executables
)
```

**I run this command:**

> python setup_fr.py build

So, a folder called "build" is created with various files and directories. But, when I run the program "hello.exe", this error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_freeze-4.3.3-py2.7-win32.egg\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)   File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\gtk\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    import gobject as _gobject   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gobject\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from glib import spawn_async, idle_add, timeout_add, timeout_add_seconds, \   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\glib\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from glib._glib import *   File "ExtensionLoader_glib__glib.py", line 22, in <module>   File "ExtensionLoader_glib__glib.py", line 14, in __bootstrap__ ImportError: DLL load failed: Could not find the specified module.
```

I've looked at the "Build" folder to see if missing something related to gobject and found the "gobject._gobject.pyd" "libcairo-gobject-2.dll" and "GObject-2.0.typelib" files. I do not know exactly which file is still missing.

**Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **gnome** dir, which by itself is in the **site-packages** dir and manually copy all the .dll files (not the nested one) from this dir to your **build/your-application-dir/** dir.
And it will work.